# Typescript: Why is it that we cannot assign default value to generic type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Take the below for instance. I'm not quite sure what the error message means, but it seems that logically, the signature is completely valid. Is this just not supported by TS?

```
function _createNominalCollection<isOutputOrdered_T extends boolean>(
  input: nominal_T,
  processingFunc: (count: number) => number,
  orderedOutput: isOutputOrdered_T = true,
)

^^^
Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'isOutputOrdered_T'.
  'boolean' is assignable to the constraint of type 'isOutputOrdered_T', but 'isOutputOrdered_T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'boolean'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: What if somebody calls `_createNominalCollection<false>()`? Also, why does this really need to be a generic?

Comment: it's not clear to me what `orderedOutput: isOutputOrdered_T = true,` is supposed to be, this looks like assignment, but can't do assignment to a type

Comment: The output changes depending on if `orderedOutput_T` is set. So something like `isOutputOrdered_T extends true ? Ta : Tb`. The `= true` is me trying to assign a default value to make the parameter optional (i.e. the output defaults to being ordered)

Comment: @Ski it's a default value. However, since it's TS, it also includes the type. A simplified version would be [`(x: number = 41) => x + 1`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZmGBeGAKAHgLhmArgWwCMBTAJ2RgBYBGASmQD4YAoGGdGAahmoG5nmoSCAA2xAHQiQAc1QJUtWvyERREqbPnU6SoA) - `x` is a parameter which is a number and if not passed in, it's going to get the value `41`.

Answer (score 9):

As @VLAZ pointed out `_createNominalCollection<false>()` is problematic. Let's look at this error again:

> 'boolean' is assignable to the constraint of type 'isOutputOrdered_T', but 'isOutputOrdered_T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'boolean'.ts(2322)

What that means is that you pass an explicit `<false>` type as the generic parameter, `isOutputOrdered_T` is now constrained to `false` but then the default argument is `true`, which would violate that.

Or to put it another way, `true` and `false` are subtypes of `boolean`, and your function allows the boolean to be constrained to one of those subtypes, but doesn't guarantee assignments to that variable will all be of that same subtype.

Let me propose an alternative.

---

When you have a function that returns different types based on different arguments, you should always consider if [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) are better suited to model that instead of generics. They allow you to specifically map argument patterns to specific return type in a simple way without any generics at all.

For example:

```js
// sorted version
function myFn(orderedOutput?: true): 'sorted'

// unsorted version
function myFn(orderedOutput: false): 'unsorted'

// Implementation
function myFn(orderedOutput: boolean = true): 'sorted' | 'unsorted' {
  return orderedOutput ? 'sorted' : 'unsorted'
}

// Testing
const a = myFn(true) // sorted
const b = myFn(false) // unsorted
const c = myFn() // sorted
```

Here you create two signatures for your function. The first "sorted" version accepts no argument or `true`. The second "unsorted" version accepts `false`. Then you have an implementation that handle both cases.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=27#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4DEwAo4CcAmAprofgPIhQAOlA-AFyJS4iECUjARAM55SmcAUKEiwEKDNjxES5SjSiNgAQwA23dl3C9c-fEJHR4SNJhwFipCtUqMARnDirCypAF4mLTYgDkOvT6IAD6+2nykgQDegoiIJFAguEjSlnI2UIi0vv4RiIw+YboRggC+goIA9BWIACqE3LBgAOaCEAgNiMqIHqbYzKxsiFWIOfit7Rl23RJmKursQ9WFeuNgHRDTvViDw6NAA)

Comment: I'm actually using overloads right now. The problem I've found with overloads is that if I want to called `myFn` in a second order function, I'm unable to do so. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4DEwAo4CcAmAprofgPIhQAOlA-AFyJS4iECUjARAM55SmcAUKEiwEKDNjxES5SjSgNEwAIYAbbuy7heufviEjo8JGkw4CxUhWqVGAIzhw1hFUgC8TFlsRvUiAG9BREQSKBBcJGkrOVsoRFpEAHJdfSTERiSdPlIkwQBfQUEAemLEABVCblgwAHNBCARq30RPM2xmVjZEUsRU0gam+PtWiXNVDXYesuy9AcawZohR9qxu3v78It6AZUIF-ERo3GVwYwRhM7EkTQOyS1xzTsIJzQcnFzc2IJCwiNNJFhnq92ABuApFBbNfjNTy3BDkB5PbzrMoAOUIADdiAAaRD2SiIQgADyo+3iPByBiAA)

Comment: Hmm, I see your point. Generics it is! The closest I can get with a generic approach then is this: https://tsplay.dev/weeXew which works except for the implementation type error, which I'm not immediately sure how to resolve.

Comment: @user1543574 but why do you need really need to know the return at compile time? Presumably *at runtime* you don't know what the input is. If you do, then this is more of a lookup table than a function. If you call `myFn(x)` where `x: boolean`, you'd get an error. Which means that a valid call is only `if(x) myFn(x); else myFn(x);` which starts being ridiculous. [Demo](https://tsplay.dev/WGnPkm)

Comment: I will know what the input is during compile time since the input will be an explicit "true" or "false" value. The problem is just that I won't be calling the function directly, but through a second order function that acts as a wrapper of sorts.

Comment: You can declare interface separately from function if you're dealing with 2nd order function and considering that your interfaces are little complicates it could be a good idea to do so
`
interface MyFn {
   (): 1
   (false): 2
}

const myFn: MyFn = (a) => ...
`

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get this error, is because isOutputOrdered_T could be a boolean subtype like `type truthy = true` or `type falsy = false` instead of being a complete boolean like `type bool = true | false`. For example:

```
function _createNominalCollection<T extends boolean>(
  orderedOutput: T
) {}

type booleanSubtype = true;

_createNominalCollection<booleanSubtype>(false);
```

In this example the compiler would complain about passing false, because *booleanSubtype* only allows true as input:

> Argument of type 'false' is not assignable to parameter of type 'true'

In case of a truthy boolean subtype, like in the example, your default value wouldn't be a valid input and thats why the compiler is warning you. Your example could work without compiler warning if you typecast your default value like this:

```
function _createNominalCollection<T extends boolean>(
  orderedOutput: T = false as T
) {}
```

But as shown before, this wouldn't be actually correct with a truthy subtype, just getting rid of the error.

Comment: I would just say a "subtype" and be done with it. "boolean like" can confuse people as this is extremely unlikely we ever get a boolean that is not `true` or `false` + "like" can be interpreted as "truthy"/"falsy".

Comment: This is true for boolean, but i wanted to somewhat express that this is true for any type which certainly can be more complex than booleans

Comment: That's true, I don't disagree - just mentioning that either an example where a subtype can be other than `true`/`false` or a different term would hold less potential for confusion (and thus make the explanation even more helpful).

Answer (score 1):

You have option to not assign default to false - leave it as undefined.

```
function f<T extends boolean=false>(a?: T) {
   return a ? 'isTrue' : 'isNotTrue'
}
```

Thought I'd question why do you need this generic in first place. Does return type change depending on this flag? If it does change why does it need to be single function, would it not make more sense to have 2 distinctly named functions?

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because you assign `true` to `orderedOutput` as a default parameter.

If you would call `_createNominalCollection(..,..,false)` the constrainted type parameter `isOutputOrdered_T` would be inferred to `false`. Of course it is not allowed to assign the value `true` to a parameter of type `false`.